# Как найти файл название которого начинается с символов .!

Tags: bash

Есть файлы названия которых начинается на **.!** например `.!example.txt` ,  `.!example1.txt` . Как найти такие файлы ? Пробовал такой способ: `find . -regex '^.*.!*\.txt$'`

Comment: Например, так `find . -iname '.!*'`

Comment: @nobody, `i` не надо. просто `-name`. ведь в шаблоне нет ни одной буквы.

Comment: ну... можно заморичится "как преобразовать маску в regex" из топ 10 гугла http://web.izjum.com/convert-mask-to-regexp

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну не то, чтоб "не надо", скорее "не обязательно", я бы даже сказал - "избыточно", именно поэтому я и написал там _например_ :)

Comment: @nobody, нет, именно "не надо": поиск будет происходить быстрей.

Comment: @nobody спасибо большое, работает.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо за ссылку, я думаю не стоит заморачиваться так как итак все нормально работает.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляю общий ответ:

```
find . -name '.!*'
```

вариант: [nobody](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199545/nobody)

что бы исключить директории из вывода поиска дополнить команду ключем `-type f`

в дальнейшую обработку перенаправить полученный список файлов можно ключем `-exec`
используется в конце выражения. синтаксис `-exec command {} \;`